# Specific-sized grids such as 49x49 in Photoshop for sprite generation?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grids, pixel-art

I need to generate sprites where images must not intersect. How can I get a custom-sized grid in Photoshop?

Comment: do you know about http://www.spritecow.com/ ?

Comment: Compass does spriting too: http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/. Sprites usually shouldn't be hand-built.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Photoshop plugin for creating grids that it is called [GuideGuide](http://guideguide.me/)

Answer (score 0):

## To change the grid to a specific size go to:

`Edit` `>` `Preferences` `>` `Guides, Grid & Slices`

There you have the option to change the default values of `Gridline Every` x `number of pixels/centimeters` etc..

To use the gird:

Go to:  `View` `>` `Show Grid`.

Note: Make sure the option "Snap to grid" is checked:

`View` `>` `Snap` `>` `Snap to Grid`

## On topic, here are some usefull Photoshop scripts:

Photoshop Grid Generator: https://gist.github.com/TaKUMA7/4023076

This one generates css position for sprites: http://arnaumarch.com/en/sprites.html

Generate CSS position for `:hover`   http://www.interactivellama.com/blog/archives/photoshop-script-combine-two-images-css-hover-css-sprite/

Check out this article for more usefull PS scripts:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/04/useful-photoshop-tools-and-techniques-for-your-workflow/